# Деплой телеграм бота Java на Heroku

Tags: java, github, telegram-bot, telegram, heroku

Есть телеграм бот написанный на JAVA - https://github.com/altmf/questbot. Хочу его скопировать и запустить на Heroku. Как это правильно сделать? Есть знающие люди, очень нужно.
Вот статья по этому боту - https://habr.com/ru/post/346112/

Answer (score 0):

Вообще есть два основных способа развернуть приложение на heroku:

- Через Git [Deploy with Git](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git) или просто подключить GitHub репозиторий
- Через плагин heroku для maven [Deploying with maven plugin](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java-applications-with-the-heroku-maven-plugin)

Второй способ легче, но, на мой взгляд, первый предпочтительнее.

Если вы впервые деплоите на heroku, я бы посоветовал вам использовать maven plugin:

Официальные инструкции я привел выше. Но вкратце нужно

- Создать приложение на самом heroku
- Добавить плагин в pom.xml

  ```
  <build>
  <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>com.heroku.sdk</groupId>
          <artifactId>heroku-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.8</version>
          <configuration>
              <appName>yourAppName_on_Heroku</appName>
              <processTypes>
                  <worker>
                      java $JAVA_OPTS -cp target/classes:target/dependency/* path.to.your.Main-class
                  </worker>
              </processTypes>
          </configuration>
      </plugin>
  </plugins>
  ```
- Также вам нужно будет установить [Heroku CLI](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-cli) и запустить команду

> heroku login

И когда вы будете готовы деплоить приложение, просто используйте:

> mvn heroku:deploy

Comment: Пытался задеплоить как сказано, но ничего не получилось, но неудачно. Вот, что пишет:-----> Java app detected
-----> Installing JDK 1.8... done
-----> Installing Maven 3.3.9... done
-----> Executing: mvn -DskipTests clean dependency:list install
       [INFO] Scanning for projects...
       [ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:

Comment: [FATAL] Non-parseable POM /tmp/build_51fe26b15dfbab53443752c2a25744e1/pom.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'dependencies' (position: START_TAG seen ...</plugins>        \n<dependencies>... @29:15)  @ line 29, column 15
        @ 
       [ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]

Comment: [ERROR]   
       [ERROR]   The project  (/tmp/build_51fe26b15dfbab53443752c2a25744e1/pom.xml) has 1 error
       [ERROR]     Non-parseable POM /tmp/build_51fe26b15dfbab53443752c2a25744e1/pom.xml: Unrecognised tag: 'dependencies' (position: START_TAG seen ...</plugins>        \n<dependencies>... @29:15)  @ line 29, column 15 -> [Help 2]
       [ERROR] 
       [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
       [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
       [ERROR]

Comment: [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
       [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
       [ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ModelParseException
 !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
       We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
       please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
 !     Push failed

Comment: @YeldarSagyn судя по логам, вы неправильно настроили pom.xml